# How to use <button> tag in wordpress?

Tags: forms, buttons

I am using a custom form without plugin. I have the following code:

```
    <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="/contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                           <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
               </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mt-3">
                       <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Send</button>
                  </div>
</form>
```

I click on the Send button but nothing is happened. How to add a click event on  to load the action file when the form is filled?

Comment: No click event is required. Your form will be submitted to /contact_process.php. Have you created that file? Is it in the root directory of your site?

Comment: you should not be submitting directly to a PHP file in your theme/plugin, it's a major security risk, and there will be problems when the file tries to use WordPress functions in that file too. Handle the form in the same file that displays the form and have an empty action attribute, it also makes it easier to do validation and show error messages if you need to display the form again